Onscreen Keyboard for Lubuntu 24.04
I just installed Lubuntu 24.04 and I cannot find any onscreen keyboard. I am using a Surface Pro 7+. I have had Ubuntu 24.04 and it had an onscreen Keyboard, however, it did not always work correctly.

Use Onboard.
sudo apt install onboard

Afterward, you can use onboard setting to turn it on as a floating icon, so that you can open it with a simple tap whenever you need it.
You can dock it to edge using onboard preferences.

